# Clara.io (or) ThreeJS: Extruded face renders grey, or doesn't render material

Tags: three.js, face, clara.io

(Note:  I've posted this on the Clara.io Forums and while it's only been a day, I've not received any replies.  I figured I'd try StackOverflow and update my Clara.io post.)

I'm hoping (guessing) that this is a quick-fix and that I'm missing something basic, but I've searched for quite a bit of time looking for a solution.  I'm seeing my final render has the color grey in place of the assigned material, whereas all other non-extruded faces render fine.

I'm learning the Clara.io interface, (along with the basic essentials of 3D modeling really), and have a basic cube with a few extruded faces.   In the screenshot below you can see the normals of all faces, including the extruded ones.   This is a result of Dr. Google saying "look at your normals, they're probably flipped".   It doesn't appear so.

[image: Clara.io Extrude]

While I put this in the "Rendering" category, I could've also applied it to "ThreeJS" as I'm wondering if it's something I've configured wrong in the ThreeJS scene.   I'm using a *MeshStandardMaterial* along with a normal and roughness map:

```
var materialTest5 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
  normalMap: textureLoaderQ.load( "/textures/metal18/metal_plates_18_nm.jpg" ),
  roughnessMap: textureLoaderQ.load( "/textures/metal18/metal_plates_18_rough.jpg" ),
    map:  textureLoaderQ.load( "/textures/metal18/metal_plates_18_dif.jpg" )
} );

var loader5 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader5.load( "/models/capsule/test-01.obj", function ( group ) {
  for ( var index = 0; index < group.children.length; index++ ) {
        var geometry = group.children[ index ].geometry;
        var meshTest5 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialTest5 );
        scene.add( meshTest5 );
  }
} );
```

They appear like this:

[image: In ThreeJS scene using a MeshStandardMaterial]

You can see the grey faces.  Try as I might, I can't get those faces to render using the same maps as the other faces.  I've tried flipping normals, I've tried altering the material in ClaraIO, and a few other settings that were futile.

Within the Clara.io, I can see a similar situation:

[image: Same after Material applied within Clara.io]

Anyone see this before?  Have an idea?

Thank you.

Jon

[**UPDATE**]  Here are the OBJ and MTL files I'm using:

[OBJ](https://pastebin.com/z7wE89Bx)
[MTL](https://pastebin.com/BtbWCBFv)

MTL

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Standard
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd metal_plates_18_dif.jpg
```

OBJ   (Not too many points, so I figured I could add it here too).

```
# Blender v2.74 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib test-01.mtl
o Box
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.000000
v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000
v 0.500000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.500000 0.000000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.000000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.000000
v -0.615470 0.615470 0.615470
v -0.500000 0.000000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.500000 0.000000 0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.000000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v 0.000000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.000000 0.500000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.506330 0.500000
v 0.000000 -0.500000 0.500000
v 0.000000 -0.500000 0.000000
v 0.000000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.500000
v 0.000000 0.000000 -0.500000
v -0.615470 0.115470 0.115470
v -0.615470 0.615470 0.115470
v -0.615470 0.115470 0.615470
v -0.115470 0.615470 0.615470
v -0.115470 0.615470 0.115470
v -0.115470 0.115470 0.615470
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.500000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 0.500000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 0.500000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn -0.707100 0.000000 -0.707100
vn -0.707100 -0.707100 0.000000
vn 0.707100 0.707100 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.707100 -0.707100
vn 0.000000 -0.707100 0.707100
vn 0.707100 0.000000 0.707100
usemtl Standard
s 1
f 1/1/1 4/2/1 5/3/1 2/4/1
f 2/4/1 5/3/1 6/5/1 3/6/1
f 4/2/1 7/7/1 8/8/1 5/3/1
f 5/3/1 8/8/1 9/9/1 6/5/1
f 10/1/2 13/2/2 14/3/2 11/4/2
f 28/4/2 27/3/2 29/5/2 12/6/2
f 13/2/2 16/7/2 17/8/2 14/3/2
f 14/3/2 17/8/2 18/9/2 15/5/2
f 10/1/3 11/2/3 20/3/3 19/4/3
f 19/4/3 20/3/3 2/5/3 3/6/3
f 28/2/3 12/7/3 30/8/3 31/3/3
f 20/3/3 21/8/3 1/9/3 2/5/3
f 18/1/4 17/2/4 23/3/4 22/4/4
f 22/4/4 23/3/4 8/5/4 7/6/4
f 17/2/4 16/7/4 24/8/4 23/3/4
f 23/3/4 24/8/4 9/9/4 8/5/4
f 12/1/5 29/2/5 32/3/5 30/4/5
f 21/4/5 25/3/5 4/5/5 1/6/5
f 15/2/5 18/7/5 22/8/5 25/3/5
f 25/3/5 22/8/5 7/9/5 4/5/5
f 3/1/6 6/2/6 26/3/6 19/4/6
f 19/4/6 26/3/6 13/5/6 10/6/6
f 6/2/6 9/7/6 24/8/6 26/3/6
f 26/3/6 24/8/6 16/9/6 13/5/6
f 11/7/7 14/7/7 27/7/7 28/7/7
f 14/7/8 15/7/8 29/7/8 27/7/8
f 21/7/9 20/7/9 31/7/9 30/7/9
f 20/7/10 11/7/10 28/7/10 31/7/10
f 15/7/11 25/7/11 32/7/11 29/7/11
f 25/7/12 21/7/12 30/7/12 32/7/12
```

[**UPDATE 2**]  Problem solved thanks to a comment @manthrax made below.

I rebuilt the UV map using the Clara.io "UV Map" option in the Object Tools section.  I also had to set the "Projection" to "Box" so the newly created extruded faces didn't have a skewed/angled diffuse layout.   While initially I had only included a "diffuse" image, I added both a "normal" and "specular" map this time around.  The image below is a bit bright, and loses the metallicity of my original render above, but that's because I put the specular to white (#ffffff).   I'll play around with those settings next.  Here's the final result:

[image: After the UV Map rebuild]

I also wanted to note that I had to change the Three JS code a bit, to handle the MTL file that Clara.io generated:

```
var meshZ = null;

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( "/models/capsule/" );
mtlLoader.load( 'test-01.mtl', function( materials ) {
  materials.preload();
  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
  objLoader.setPath( "/models/capsule/" );
  objLoader.load( 'test-01.obj', function ( object ) {
    meshZ = object;
    scene.add( meshZ );
  } );
} );
```

Thanks again, @manthrax.

Onto the next 3D OBJ creation learning curve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you loader.load callback.. instead of looping through children, can you try:

```
group.traverse((e)=>{if(e.material)e.material = materialTest5;})
```

instead of looping through children?

Also, could you post your .OBJ file so we can take a look?

Comment: I've tried the snippet you've provided and it produces the same results.   I'm actually seeing that grey rendering not only in my own ThreeJS code, but in the actual Clara.io renderer as well.   I've updated my post with Pastebin links for both the OBJ and MTL files.   Thanks much.

Comment: Ahhh i see... Yeah it looks like the extrusion operation isn't generating texture coordinates. You might need to perform a UV unwrap to generate them. Might I suggest learning Blender?

Comment: "Might I suggest learning Blender?"   It appears that I'm heading in that direction.  I have a massive ThreeJS project where I'll need to generate OBJ files and I'm currently looking at applications that will allow me to do so with minimal learning curve.  So far I've looked at Blender, Hexagon, Rhino3D, and Clara.io, (as well as a few "CADs": TinkerCad, SelfCad, and FreeCad).    With Rhino3D it's the price that's holding me back.  With Blender it's the learning curve.   Thanks for the feedback/help.   I'll look at the unwrap mechanism of Blender.

Comment: If you want some mentoring with Blender, hit me up in this slack channel..

I am @thrax

https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: Wow, thanks for the offer.  I will most likely take you up on that.    Your comment about UV unwrap led to the solution, (just posted).   Thanks for saving me some time, (and headache).  Have a good one.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help.